# Сгенерировать матрицу, которая при умножении на вектор дает его отклонение от среднего значения

Tags: python, numpy, матрицы

Задача заключается в том, чтобы создать матрицу А, которая при умножении на вектор дает результат его отклонения от среднего значения, Ax = x - mean. При этом, матрица А не должна зависеть от значений входящего вектора х, а только от его длины (т.е. для создания матрицы должно быть достаточно только знания сколько в х элементов).

Есть мнение, что можно преобразовать и упростить следующее выражение:

(A-I)x = -x@i/len(x)

Comment: Что такое -х@i ?

Comment: это выражение аналогично скалярному произведению векторов x.dot(i), где i принято считать единичным вектором (в данном случае такой же длины как х)

Comment: Ну, т.е. среднее как оно есть. Понятно. Т.е. справа -  вектор (mean), в котором все элементы равны между собой. Тем не менее,   абсолютно непонятно, как  можно удовлетворить условие "для создания матрицы должно быть достаточно только знания сколько в х элементов", так как среднее зависит не только от количества элементов, но и от их значений.  И в такой постановке как мне кажется задача имеет бесконечное число решений -  вам надо найти  N*N коэффициентов матрицы но у вас есть N+1 уравнений.

Comment: опубликовала задачу на математическом форуме: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4149565/how-to-find-matrix-a-which-multiplied-by-vector-x-returns-the-deviation-of-x-fro - очень быстро нашелся ответ!

Comment: Finally A is the matrix whose all entries are equal to −1/n except the diagonals ones which are equal to (n−1)/n. Ага, только это не единственное решение. Возьмем пример - вектор (1,2,3). Да, приведенная выше матрица есть решением. Но решением есть и матрица - в нотации списка Python -  [[0,1,-1], [1,1,-1],[-4,1,1]] - совершенно не симметричная и с совершенно произвольными диагональными  элементами.  Как и бесконечное множество других решений, кстати.

Comment: @passant спасибо за комментарий. В моем условии задачи, которое возможно я не до конца расскрыла в этом посте, нужно было написать функцию, которая создает матрицу  исключительно с одним входящим аргументом - это длина вектора х. Математики феноменально справились с решением, до конца правда не поняла как у них получилось сократить х, но это именно то, что было нужно. Функция опубликована ниже, если остались вопросы, пишите.

Answer (score 0):

Задача заключалась в том, чтобы упростить матричное уравнение. В целом, решение может быть рассмотрено следующим образом:

*A * X = X - Mean*           # исходное уравнение

*X - Mean = X - i * Mean(X)* # отнимаем среднее значение от каждого элемента вектора Х

*A * X = X - i * i.T * X/len(X)* # находим среднее значение

*A * X = (I - (1/len(X)) * i * i.T) * X* # выносим Х за скобки и получаем матрицу А

```
    def gen_m(n):
        J = np.ones(shape=(n,n))
        I = np.eye(n)
        return I - J/n
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]